# incomplete type support for list

Tags: c++11, stl

I implemented a list with similar API to `std::list` but it fails to compile

```
struct A { my_list<A> v; };
```

The list has a base class that has a member a `base_node` which has the `prev` and `next` fields and `node` (which is derived from `base_node`) holds the `T` value (which is the template parameter for the list). The compilation error is

```
error: ‘node<T>::val’ has incomplete type
     T val;
       ^~~
note: forward declaration of ‘struct A’
```

I looked in GCC code and it seems like they hold a buffer of bytes of size T so not sure how it works for them. How `std::list` manages to store `A` in its nodes?
[image]

[UPDATE]

```
struct A { };

template <typename T>
struct B : public A
{
    using B_T = B<T>;
    T t;
};

template <typename T>
class C
{
    using B_T = typename B<T>::B_T; // this fails to compile
    //using B_T = B<T>; // this compiles fine
};

struct D { C<D> d; };
```

Comment: Your description of the code is very vague and unclear. I cannot get the relation between `my_list`, `node` and `base_node`. Try to update the Q with a reproducible example.

Comment: The code is long. `struct A { std::list<A> v; };` is taken from LLVM tests and it compiles, but I'm not sure how. I'm not sure how they detach the type held by list nodes from list compilation

Comment: Cannot reproduce based on your diagram and description: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b41e97113d13de05

Comment: Probably the pasted compiler error is followed by a sequence of "required from..." notes which might help spot what's in your code and not in mine causing the problem.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you. I was able to reproduce it with your code, I will refactor my code based on your example, feel free to write an answer so I can accept it
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/450f05eba3710a7b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simplified example

```
struct A { };

template <typename T>
struct B : public A
{
    using B_T = B<T>;
    T t;
};

template <typename T>
class C
{
    using B_T = typename B<T>::B_T; // this fails to compile
    //using B_T = B<T>; // this compiles fine
};

struct D { C<D> d; };
```

you're running into the gotchas of class template instantiation.

First, note that a class definition has essentially two parse passes (not necessarily implemented this way):

1. First determine the types of base classes and class members. During this process, the class is considered incomplete, although previously declared bases and members can be used by later code in the definition.
2. In some pieces of code within the class definition which does not affect the types of bases or members, the class is considered complete. These places include member function definition bodies, member function default arguments, static member initializers, and non-static member default initializers.

For example:

```
struct S {
    std::size_t n = sizeof(S);                  // OK, S is complete

    std::size_t f() const { return sizeof(S); } // OK, S is complete

    using array_type = int[sizeof(S)];          // Error, S incomplete

    void f(int (&)[sizeof(S)]);                 // Error, S incomplete
};
```

Templates make this trickier because they make it easier to accidentally indirectly use a class which is not yet complete. This particularly comes up in CRTP code, but this example is another simple way it can happen.

The basic way class template instantiation works (a bit simplified) is:

- Just naming a class template specialization, like `X<Y>`, does not by itself cause the class template to be instantiated.
- Using a class template specialization in ways valid for an incomplete class type does not cause the template to be instantiated.
- Using a class template specialization in any way which requires the type to be complete, like naming a member of the class or defining a variable with the class type (not pointer or reference), causes an implicit instantiation of the template.
- Instantiating a class template involves determining the types of the base classes and members, much like the "first pass" of class definition parsing. All those base and member types must be valid at that time. Instantiating member definitions is for the most part delayed until each member is needed, but there is no selective instantiation of member types in this step: it's all or error.
- The process can be recursive when a base class or member declaration involves another template specialization. But during that other instantiation, the class type for the original instantiation context is considered incomplete.

Looking at the example, `struct D` defines a member `C<D> d;` which requires `C<D>` to be complete, so we attempt to instantiate the specialization `C<D>`. So far, `D` is incomplete.

There's just one member of `C<D>`, which is

```
using B_T = typename B<D>::B_T;
```

Since this names a member of another class template specialization `B<D>`, now we have to attempt to instantiate that `B<D>` specialization. So far, `D` and `C<D>` are still incomplete.

`B<D>` has one base class, which is just `A`. It has two members:

```
using B_T = B<D>;
D t;
```

The member type `B<D>::B_T` is fine since just naming `B<D>` doesn't require a complete type. But instantiating `B<D>` requires both members to be well-formed. A class member can't have an incomplete class as its type, but type `D` is still incomplete right now.

As you noticed, you can work around this by avoiding naming the member `B<T>::B_T` and directly using the type `B<T>` instead. Or you could move the original `B_T` definition to some other base class or traits struct, and make sure its new location is one that *can* be instantiated with an incomplete type as argument.

Many templates just assume their arguments must always be complete types. But they can be useful in more situations if they're carefully written with considerations about how the code uses template arguments and other indirectly used dependent types, which might be incomplete at the point of instantiation.